# Add parts to variable[]

Tags: java

Is there a way to add parts to a variable[], when the amount of parts is not constant?

For example:

```
 String[] S = {"hello", "hello1", "hello2"};
```

I want to add

```
String S2 = "hello3"
```

with something like this:

```
S = S + {S2}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is what you need

Comment: That is what `ArrayList` is there for.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.  They grow dynamically.

Comment: Use List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>() and add all the String with result.add("hello3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) if you are working with a variable number of elements.

Your code would be somethink like this:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add("Hello");
s.add("Hello1");
s.add("Hello2");

String s2 = "hello3"
s.add(s2);
```

Also, its  a Java convention to name your variables starting in lowercase, so it would be `s` instead of `S`.

Comment: Line 1 should be `List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();`. Otherwise you have a syntax error since `String` cannot be parametrized

Comment: @MikeKoch Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: No problem.  Also just adding an FYI for the OP: If you're using a version of Java under 1.7 (which I don't know why you would be), you need to specify the datatype after `ArrayList` (`'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows without using a list -

```
String[] arr = {"hello", "hello1", "hello2"};
String s = "hello3";

arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1); // replace 1 with no of additional elements
arr[arr.length - 1] = s;
```